# Cannot properly traverse a Binary tree to retrieve all LeftChild and RightChild to extract to a String

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Hello I am trying to write a method that will visit all the nodes in a binary tree and add the item name at that node, and the number of occurences of item [this data has been enqueued properly]. and this is what the data in the binary tree will look like...
[image]

when I run the print command [in separate main program... that call this....]] I get the following...

```
blow: 2
mm: 1
blow: 2
```

I am stuck trying to get the expected result with should be...

```
blow:2
cc:1
ee:2
mm:1
nn:1
pp:2
oo:1
```

[As oo is a child of pp, I have put it last]

Here is my code...

```
    //========================================================================= 
        /*
         *  This method returns a string of the items of the binary tree on a new line
         */
        @Override
        public String print() 
        {
    
    
            // Placeholder, please update.
            BT_node current=root;
            // Placeholder, please update.
            String result="";
            // this is a string to hold the concatenation of the array elements
            
            
            
            
            //go through the left nodes
            while (current.leftChild != null) 
            {
                if(current.leftChild!=null)
                {
                    current = current.leftChild;
                    result= result + "\n"+current.getitem()+": "+current.getnumber() ;  
                    
                    if(current.leftChild==null)
                    {
                        current = current.rightChild ;
                    }//close if(current.leftChild==null)
                    
                }//close if(current.leftChild!=null)
                else if (current.rightChild != null)
                {
                    current = current.rightChild;
                    result= result + "\n"+current.getitem()+": "+current.getnumber() ;  
                    
                    if(current.rightChild==null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }//close if(current.leftChild==null)
                    
                    
                }//close (current.rightChild != null)
                
            }// close while (current.leftChild != null) 
            
            //System.out.println(result);
            
            current=root;
            result= result + "\n"+current.getitem()+": "+current.getnumber() ;
            
            //current=root;
            // go through the right nodes
            while (current.rightChild != null) 
            {
                if(current.leftChild!=null)
                {
                    current = current.leftChild;
                    result= result + "\n"+current.getitem()+": "+current.getnumber() ;  
                    
                    if(current.leftChild==null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }//close if(current.leftChild==null)
                    
                }//close if(current.leftChild!=null)
                else if (current.rightChild != null)
                {
                    current = current.rightChild;
                    result= result + "\n"+current.getitem()+": "+current.getnumber() ;  
                    
                    if(current.rightChild==null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }//close if(current.leftChild==null)
                    
                }//close (current.rightChild != null)
            }// close 
            
            //System.out.println(result);
            
            //return new String();
            return result;
    
    
        } // end of OrderedPrint
```

And here is the code for the Binary tree node class..

```
    public class BT_node 
{
    // define class variables
    BT_node leftChild;
    // these nodes hold values less that 
    BT_node rightChild;
    String  item;
    // this is the name  of the item being stored.
    // It is the element
    
    int number;
    //This stores the number of occurences of the item
    // this is the itemCount
    
    

    
    //==========================================================================
    /*
     * class constructor
     */ 
    
    
    public BT_node(String item, int number) 
    // this is the constructor used by BSTNode
    {
        this.item = item;
        this.number = number;
        this.leftChild = null;
        // This stores values less than node value
        this.rightChild = null;
        // This stores valies greater than the node value
    }//close public BTNode(String item, int number) 
    
    
    //==========================================================================
    /*
     * this returns the itement as a string
     */ 
    public String toString() 
    {
        return item.toString();
    }// close public String toString() 
    
    
    
    //==========================================================================
    /*
     * this returns the itement 
     */     
    public String getitem() 
    {
        return item;
    }// close public String getitem() 
    
    
    //==========================================================================
    /*
     * this sets the itement 
     */ 
    public void setitem(String item) 
    {
        this.item = item;
    }//close public void setitem(String item)
    
    
    //==========================================================================
    /*
     * this gets the number of occurences 
     */ 
    public int getnumber() 
    {
        return number;
    }// close public int getnumber() 
    
    
    //==========================================================================
    /*
     * this this sets the number of occurnaces for the itemn
     */     
    public void setnumber(int number) 
    {
        this.number = number;
    }// close public void setnumber(int number) 
    
    
    //==========================================================================
    /*
     * this gets the leftChild
     */ 
    public BT_node getLeftChild() 
    {
        return leftChild;
    }// close public BTNode getLeftChild() 
    
    
    //==========================================================================
    /*
     * this sets the leftChild
     */     
    public void setLeftChild(BT_node leftChild) 
    {
        this.leftChild = leftChild;
    }//close public void setLeftChild(BTNode leftChild) 
    
    
    //==========================================================================
    /*
     * this gets the rightChild
     */ 
    public BT_node getRightChild() 
    {
        return rightChild;
    }//close public BTNode getRightChild()
    
    
    //==========================================================================
    /*
     * this sets the rightChild
     */ 
    public void setRightChild(BT_node rightChild) 
    {
        this.rightChild = rightChild;
    }//close public void setRightChild(BTNode rightChild) 
    
    
    
    

}// close BT_node
```

I have to admit, I am a bit weak with recursive methods, and this would be easier if I did not have to output a string back to the calling program that then prints it to a console...

I have been struggling to get it to recurse all the way down one node and add leftChild, rightChild node items to the "results" string...

Any suggestions on changes to my code would really be appreciated.

Sincerely

Comment: What I am trying to do is recurse through all nodes in the Binary tree, and add the item name of each node to a string that shall be returned after recursing through all Binary Tree nodes.

Answer (score 0):

well this could be easier to visit all the nodes in DFS fashion. The pseudocode will be look like following:

```
HM: HashMap<String, Integer>(); // String -> name of the item, Integer -> occ. of item.

Function getNameAndOcc(root, HM):

   IF (!root):  /* when the root is empty, we will get back */
       return HM;

   ELSE:
        String item = root.getItem(); /* extract item from node */
        IF (HM->containsKey(item)):   /* is item already tracked before */
               HM->PUT(item, HM->GET(item)+1);
        ELSE:
               HM->PUT(item, 1);  /* the item first time tracking */


    getNameAndOcc(root->left, HM);  // go all nodes in left side
    getNameAndOcc(root->right, HM); // go all nodes in right side
     
    return HM; // we eventually visits all nodes and we will return the result.
```

The idea is following,  we will use HashMap to keep track every item and its occurrence. We usually return from traversing when we will deal with an empty node (null node).

We will visit each node of the tree, and keep counting its occurrence in DepthFirstSearch fashion.